# how to show special page for IE6 users requesting them to upgrade in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Just like the every other web developer, I'm frustrated to hack my site code to work with IE 6. So decided to give up support for IE 6 and ask them politely to upgrade to IE 7+ or Firefox.

Can you suggest me how to detect IE6 users and display a special page showing the upgrade details in ASP.NET MVC?

Is handling this at server side scripting a good idea? or do you recommend to use any client side script like jQuery to handle this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easiest thing IMO is to create an action filter attribute.  Then you can just tag your controllers with it (or add to global filters in MVC3).

Here's the attribute:

```
/// <summary>
/// If the user has IE6, this will present them with a page that tells them they have a crappy old browser.  It gives them options to upgrade but they can also 
/// choose to proceed anyway.  This check is done only when they first visit the site.  A cookie also prevents unnecessary future checks, so this won't slow the app down.
/// </summary>
public class WarnAboutIE6Attribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        //this will be true when it's their first visit to the site (will happen again if they clear cookies)
        if (request.UrlReferrer == null && request.Cookies["browserChecked"] == null)
        {
            //give old IE users a warning the first time
            if (request.Browser.Browser.Trim().ToUpperInvariant().EqualsExact("IE") && request.Browser.MajorVersion <= 6)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData["RequestedUrl"] = request.Url.ToString();

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "InternetExplorerOldWarning" };
            }

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("browserChecked", "true"));
        }

    }
}
```

This attribute checks for IE6, and if it's present, it renders the "InternetExplorerOldWarning" view, which you have to create.  It only presents this warning once by using a cookie.  You could of course tweak that however you want.  In my view, I gave them links to update or download other browsers.  I also gave them the opportunity to continue with IE6.  Check it out:

```
            <h3>
        Your Internet Explorer is Outdated</h3>
  <div class="warning">Your version of Internet Explorer is a bit too old and unfortunately won't work well with this site.</div>
  <p>Have no fear.  You have options and in just a few minutes you can be rocking out in our app:</p>
  <ul>
  <li>If you have FireFox, Safari, or Google Chrome already on your computer use one of them for Takeoff instead.</li>
  <li>Upgrade to the <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/worldwide-sites.aspx">latest Internet Explorer.</a>  You can download and install right away.  Even Microsoft recommends you do this.</li>
  <li>Download an Internet Explorer alternative.  We recommend <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html">FireFox</a>, <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Safari</a>, or <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a>.  Choose one or all because each is great!</li>
  </ul>

  <p>This warning page will only show once.  If you really want to use Takeoff with your current Internet Explorer, we won't stop you.  But beware, it will probably look like garbage!</p>
  <p>Whatever dude, I want to <a href="@ViewData["RequestedUrl"] ">my old, insecure, scary, dangerous version</a> of Internet Explorer.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Thanks alot.

Comment: Didn't need the complete code but accessing the browser's information (`request.Browser.Browser` and `request.Browser.MajorVersion`) was the point. Good job.

Answer (score 13):

You may do the detection from the coding:

```
// ASP.net MVC C# example 
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Request.Browser.Version.ConvertTo<float>() < 7.0)
{   
    // output message to urge user to upgrade to latest IE browser 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be terrible practise to specifically serve a different non-functional page to IE6. For starters, if you're in the UK you're likely to run afoul of the DDA, for seconds (depending on your situation of course) you really don't want to just stop 20-25% of your users using your site.

A lot of people are forced into using IE6 at work. Pissing them off unneccesarily doesn't make good business sense.

That said, there's no reason to make your site look pixel-perfect. You can detect that they're using IE6 server-side with Request.UserAgent and display an unobtrusive message at the top of your home page (or at the top of every page) letting users know that their browser is very old and you don't support it anymore. Then you can either serve a specific IE6 stylesheet (very cut-down), or if IE6's rendering issues aren't so severe as to make your site unusable, you can just not bother about them.

When I'm doing internet-work these days I charge extra to support IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Showing a totally different page for IE 6 is a bit harsh IMHO, unless you want to block/redirect there is no need to validate this on the server-side.

“*Politely*” would mean that you validate the browser on the client side and show an alert/remind message to upgrade. The folks at [stoplivinginthepast.com have build a standard logic to do this](http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/get-the-code/)  based on [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) (they suggest you show a message on the top of your landing page).

[http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/get-the-code/ http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/warninggrab.jpg](http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/warninggrab.jpg)

Image courtesy: *http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/*

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer in having troubles with IE8 and less. I wanted users to user IE9 or later but with compatibility mode on IE9 showing up as IE7.

So adding on to Steve Potters answer and inspired by the following link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae715fd2-1ddd-46f7-8c26-9aed6b2103f1/how-to-detect-compatibility-mode-in-ie-any-version?forum=netfxjscript .

I changed my code to

```
public class WarnAboutIeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var isIe9Compatible = false;

        if (request.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            if (request.Browser.Browser.Trim().ToUpperInvariant().Equals("IE") && request.Browser.MajorVersion <= 8)
            {
                var useragent = request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent"); 
                if (useragent != null) isIe9Compatible = useragent[0].Contains("Trident/5.0");
                if (!isIe9Compatible) filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {ViewName = "_InternetExplorerOldWarning"};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding in hope it helps someone.